# using rereplace to find the string in the cfhttp filecontent

Tags: coldfusion

i am calling one page with `cfhttp`, and this page has very different kind of details in this page as it is using script tags to navigate to next page and i am unable to locate that thing with mine code:

here is the code which looks like as:

```
//window.location.replace("gen.asp?pagenum=-1" );
//window.location.replace("Wait.asp?Request("stateQ") & "&PDF=T" );
//window.location.replace("Gen.asp?stateQ=");
window.location.replace("GenA.asp?companyid=&stateQ=");
```

as you see here there are 3 `window.replace` and I want to fetch the one which is not commented one and add https:// to it because with the url it just shows me 404 error because it tries attach my https://url to this file which it cannot find,

i am using cfhttp as:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="#pstr#" charset="utf-8" result="objget"/>
<cfoutput>#objget.filecontent#</cfoutput>
<cfif rereplacenocase('^[window.location.replace]$')>
```

but not sure how to proceed ahead

Comment: All the lines of code look commented out. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Also, please post the actual code you tried, and the result. The code above is not valid and would not even compile.

Comment: i made an effort to write once, but i failed because i am lost how to do it.  also if you check the string @James, the last one is without the `//` , That needs to be fetched

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with string functions, you should start by reading [the documentation](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/String+functions) first.

Answer (score 0):

I am very confused by your goal here, but I feel like something like this would work.

It seems like you're trying to use ReReplace like ReFind. I'll show you this:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="#pstr#" charset="utf-8" result="objget"/>
<cfif ReFind("(GenA.asp\?companyid=(\d*)&stateQ=(\w*))",object.filecontent)>
  <cfset repcontent = ReReplaceNoCase(object.filecontent,"(GenA.asp\?companyid=(\d*)&stateQ=(\w*)","https://...stuff/\1","ALL")>
</cfif>
```

However, the ReFind is not necessary in this case, if the rereplace can't make a match, it returns the same variable as prior to the replace. (`ReFind()` is good in places where you just want to check if a value exists, or in `while` loops.)

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="#pstr#" charset="utf-8" result="objget"/>
<cfset repcontent = ReReplaceNoCase(object.filecontent,"(GenA.asp\?companyid=(\d*)&stateQ=(\w*)","https://...stuff/\1","ALL")>
```

This is more effective since the if is not needed and so no performance overhead.

Both make some assumptions, but I'm not sure the url has empty values so I show you how to do the replace regardless of the value.

- `(\d*)` (as the value of company ID) means any number of digits, 0 or more. If it's not a numeric value, you can change it
- `(\w*)` (as the value of stateQ means letters, numbers, or underscore, any number of times.
- You'll notice that the question marks are prefixed with `\`. This is not a typo, question mark is a special character in regex so you have to escape it.

Suppose that the values are more complex than that, for iether, you can change them to `([^&]*)` such as this, which means "any character except ampersand, 0 or more times.)

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="#pstr#" charset="utf-8" result="objget"/>
<cfset repcontent = ReReplaceNoCase(object.filecontent,"(GenA.asp\?companyid=([^&]*)&stateQ=([^&]*)","https://...stuff/\1","ALL")>
```

Or if the value is literally just as you showed it,

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="#pstr#" charset="utf-8" result="objget"/>
<cfset repcontent = ReplaceNoCase(object.filecontent,"GenA.asp?companyid=&stateQ=","https://...stuff/GenA.asp?companyid=&stateQ=","ALL")>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use multi-line mode with ColdFusion regexes to avoid matching the lines starting with the `//` comments, e.g:

```
<cfset newcontent = REReplaceNoCase(objget.fileContent, "(?m)^(window\.location\.replace\("")(GenA\.asp\?companyid=&stateQ=)(""\);)$", "\1https://<myurl>/\2\3") />
```

Note the use of capture groups. The first group `\1` will capture `window.location.replace("`; the second `\2` the URL you're looking to capture and replace with an `https://` URL; the third `\3` `");`. The start anchor `^` ensures that we only grab lines starting with `window.location...` and will avoid those lines that are commented out. The multi-line mode parameter `(?m)` allows this, so the anchors `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of lines, respectively, and not the beginning and end of strings. An alternative to this parameter is to use Java regular expressions and use a negative lookbehind `(?!<//)`.